# Publish desktop application working fine on my system but when I send setup to someone, it doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, localdb

I have developed a desktop c# application with `localdb`. While publishing the application, I have selected .net framework and `localdb` as a prerequisite. The published setup works fine on my system but when I send the complete setup files to any other system it doesn't work.

Here is my connection string

```
SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\StadiumDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
```

Here is what I am selecting in prerequisite

[image]

The error that I am getting on other systems.

[image]

I have gone through so many blogs and articles regarding this and none of the solutions provided is working.

Comment: does other system has ms sql server installed or did you added db .mdf in the project directory itself?

Comment: Becuase other systems dont have the localDB set up

Comment: while publish I have selected it in applications as well as it is included in the project.

Comment: @JohnM I have selected localDB as a prerequisite in the publish and I have checked on another system it is downloaded and installed in that system before application.

Comment: The tags on this question are confusing, you have both "asp.net", and "desktop".  What kind of application is actually being installed on the remote computer?

Comment: Also, can you verify on the remote computer that SqlLocalDb successfully installed with the correct instance name?  You can do this from a command prompt by running the command `sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb`.  It should list out some information about the LocalDb instance.  If you can add that output to the question, it would be helpful.

Comment: its windows form c# desktop application i am creating.

Comment: let me check that @BradleyUffner

Comment: I am getting following error "LocalDb  instance 'mssqllocaldb' doesn't exist "

Comment: @BradleyUffner here is a complete error

printing of LocalDB instance "mssqllocaldb" information failed because of the following error:
LocalDB instance "mssqllocaldb" doesn't exist!

Comment: Ok, that error means that SqlLocalDb is installed on that computer, but either no instance was created, or the one that was created doesn't have the same name as the one you expect.  Try running `sqllocaldb info` (without the mssqllocaldb instance name part).  That will list all the instances.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed something else when looking closely at your screenshot.  You are installing SqlLocalDb from SQL Server 2012.  The format of the connection string is actually different, in that the automatic default  instance is named `v11.0` instead of `mssqllocaldb`.  Changing the `Data Source` of the connection string to `(localdb)\v11.0` will probably work on that computer.  This leads me to beleive that you are running a newer version of SqlLocalDb, probably 2014 or later, locally.  These using different configs.  this could cause problems, I recommend using the same version.

Comment: yeah infor command give me 11.0 as well and i did changed it to (localdb)\v11.0 but now i am getting different error which says

The database cannot be opened because it is version 852. this server supports version 782 and earlier.A downgrade path is not supported.

Comment: That new error is most likely because you are packaging your database as part of the installation.  It was created on a different version of SQL from the one running on the target machine.  That isn't supported.  You need to somehow get everyone on the same LocalDb version, that the database was created on.

Comment: is that can be done in prerequisite step to embed new version to be downloaded before running the application or i should download new version and package it with setup files.

Comment: Finally sorted out by installing localdb.msi

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have different versions of LocalDb installed on your development machine, and the installation machine.  The default instance `MSSQLLocalDB` used to be named by version in older versions of LocalDb, `v11.0` for example.  Microsoft changed that to `MSSQLLocalDB` in a later version of LocalDB.

The fact that you say `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` works on your machine, leads me to believe that you are using that newer version.  Your screenshot shows that you have selected LocalDB from SQL 2012, which uses the default instance name `v11.0`.  This means you will need a different connection string remotely vs during development.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a good way to detect the instance name to adjust the connection string.

Running different versions of LocalDB on your development machine, and installing a different version on the remote computer, will probably cause you a lot of headaches, like this one.  I recommend either installing whatever localDb version you are developing against on the remote machine, or installing 2012 on your development machine, so that everyone has the same version.

---

Based on comments you made, your development machine is running Sql 2016 (db version 852).  You either need to install Sql 2012 on your development machine, or install 2016 as the prerequisite.

Comment: is that can be done in prerequisite step to embed new version to be downloaded before running the application or I should download the new version and package it with setup files.

Comment: It might be possible to get 2016 LocalDb in the prerequisite list by clicking the "Check Microsoft Update for more redistributable components" link in the screenshot you posted, but I can't guarantee it.  If not, you will have to find some other way to get the versions to match.